# Access from AKS to SQL Server is blocked by a firewall in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, kubernetes, vnet

I have a VNET in Azure and the AKS cluster created in that VNET and SQL Server networking and firewall applied in the same VNET.

When I tried to access the SQL Server from AKS cluster then I got the below exception.

> Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall

Could someone help to resolve this. Both the resources are in the VNET.

Comment: so whats the issue? allow aks vms to talk to sql

Answer (score 0):

See here for instructions how to create the firewall rule using VNET service endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#azure-portal-steps